# Type mismatch error 13 arrays

Tags: arrays, vba

I have read through the examples on Stackoverflow and still can't seem to get this statement right - can anyone point me to where I am going wrong please?

The error is a type mismatch at the point where I am trying to split the line of text held in `LineText` into a multidimensional array `Orders()`. I tried from `RawOrders(j)` to `Orders(y, x)` but same result.

```
Dim RawOrders() As String
Dim Orders() As String
Dim LineText As String

Dim h As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileNum As Integer

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
    RawOrders = Split(Input$(LOF(FileNum), #FileNum), vbNewLine)
Close #FileNum

ReDim Orders(3, 21)

h = 1
p = 0
j = 0
x = 0
y = 0

Do While Not RawOrders(p) = ""

    LineText = RawOrders(h)

    Do While j <> 21

        Orders(y, x) = Split(LineText, ",") *Errors out here giving Type MissMatch* 
        x = x + 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop

    y = y + 1
    h = h + 1
    p = p + 1
Loop
```

Comment: split returns an array. you have to assign the outcome of `split` to an array and loop its values to your `orders` array afterwards

Comment: if I assign a string called Order to equal the split how do I cycle through Order into orders() as RawOrders() holds 3 lines first is header row then two orders?

Comment: @psychicebola can you show me with some example code please, I just cant visualise how I would do that?

Comment: In your error line, Split is returning a 1D-array (see VBA HELP).  If you want to assign that array to an element of Orders, then Orders must be a Variant type, not a string.

Comment: Changing the array from a string to a variant worked thank you @Ron Rosenfeld

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim splitRes() as Variant 'one dimension
Dim orders()

splitRes = yoursplitfunction
ReDim Orders(3, 21)

Do While j <> 21

    Orders(y, x) = splitRes(j) 'guessing that you have 21 values in your lineText
                               'if you have less you get an error
    x = x + 1
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I still get a mismatch error on the `SplitRes = Split(LineText,",")`

Comment: did you declare `splitres` as variant? other question what datatype is `linetext`? maybe it's enough to cast it to string with `cstr(linetext)`

Comment: Changing the array from a string to a variant worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got to after changing the `Orders()` to a variant.

```
Dim Count As Integer
Dim RawOrders() As String
Dim Orders() As Variant
Dim y As Integer
Dim h As Integer

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
    RawOrders = Split(Input$(LOF(FileNum), #FileNum), vbNewLine)
Close #FileNum

Count = UBound(RawOrders, 1)

ReDim Orders(Count - 1)

h = 1
y = 0

Do While Not RawOrders(h) = ""

    Orders(y) = Split(RawOrders(h), ",")

    y = y + 1
    h = h + 1
Loop
```